# Move in direction of rotation in opengl

Tags: opengl, 3d, rotation, trigonometry, path-finding

I'm really new to OpenGL but have quite a good grasp of basic trigonometry (forgotten quite a bit since school!) but I'm having trouble with this.

I have a character that moves forwards and backwards on the Z axis. To move left and right, rather than strafing I want them to rotate (when pressing left and right arrow keys respectively) and then when they press forwards/backwards again they move in the direction they're facing.

So what I did was have the left/right functions add/subtract small amounts onto an angle variable that is used to draw the character's rotation. Then the forward/backward functions add/subtract small amounts to the x and z axes variables. They are as follows (for the backwards):

```
z -= 0.005f * Math.cos(heading);
x -= 0.005f * Math.sin(heading)
```

The heading variable is the angle which is manipulated by the left and right arrow keys.

I thought this would work because when the player is going straight forward the heading is 0 and so cos(0) = 1 and sin(0) = 0 which means they move nowhere on the X but forwards the full 0.005 amount on the Z. I guess my rudimentary trigonometry knowledge wasn't completely sound because if I turn a bit then move forwards they go in that direction but if I move a bit more then move forwards they go in that same line if it was rotated 90 degrees, and continues then again as if it was 180 degrees then 270 degrees etc.

EDIT: I'll try and explain that better, basically if I press forwards after turning to the left it will go in the direction I want, but if I let go of forward, turn a bit more and then press forward again, the angle has increased as it should have but the direction is like 90 degrees around from the direction it should be going. Sorry I can't really explain this well.

EDIT: Okay, I'm getting some weird problems that I think might be causing the strange "90 degrees" problem, When I get the character to look 90 degrees (through hard-coding heading=90) left/right, cos(heading) should be 0 right? But for some reason it is coming out as -0.44, and If I cos-1(-0.44) I get 116.1, is it something to do with Math.cos() wanting the angle in radians or something? I'm completely lost here.

Is this the right way of going about this problem? I'm completely stuck just trial and erroring around with minus signs...

Any reply is appreciated,

Thanks

InfinitiFizz

(Also, I know I should use a deltaTime for the speed/rotation values of the character not a hard-coded 0.005f but I want to get this problem out of the way first before I sort that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be * not +

based on:

```
x = r cos (theta)
y = r sin (theta)
```

you will want:

```
z -= 0.005f * Math.cos(heading);
x -= 0.005f * Math.sin(heading);
```

If that's what you're after? I must admit, I didn't fully understand your description of what actually happens.

EDIT: you'll probably want to use a larger "radius" than 0.005, depending on how your coordinate system is working.

Comment: Ah sorry I had * not + but wrote it wrong in my question. Also, the 0.005 isn't the radius, it's the amount the player moves when the up/down arrow is pressed. So before I added the trig, it moved forward and backward 0.005, but now a percentage of that 0.005 goes in the direction based on the angle.

Comment: Hi Fizz. Yeah, in terms of the trig, it is the radius, but for your calculation, it is the scalar speed. That's why I stuck it in quotes. You're converting the scalar speed (the hypotenuse of the right angled triangle, or the radius of the circle) into a velocity vector (the opposite and adjacent sides of that triangle, or the coordinates of that point of the circle's circumference made by that radius). So do you have it working now?

Comment: Oh, I've just read the edit to your question. Could you tell us how you're working out "heading"? And am I right in saying Z increases as you go up the screen, and X increases as you go right?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comments before I did those edits. Z decreases as I go up the screen and X increases to the right but that's just the way I've set up the camera so I can change that any time. Ah I understand what you mean about it is the radius as I'm using it in the h * cos(theta) equation. I am working out heading by += and -= it when the left and right arrows are pressed so holding down right for some time will increase the heading value at a rate of 0.05f (or any number) and then when forward is pressed it is put into the math.cos(heading).

Comment: Hmm... It all sounds right to me! Will it be possible to find out what Math.cos and Math.sin are returning, and what heading is, when it goes wrong? Sin should be negative when heading is between PI and (2*PI), and also negative when heading is between 0 and -PI. Cos should be negative when heading is between PI/2 and (3*PI)/2, and also negative when heading is between -PI/2 and -(3*PI)/2. I assume you're working in radians? And you're not limiting heading at all?

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for persisting with this :-). I added another Edit to the main question saying that I'm getting a weird cos result for 90 degrees and wondered if that was because I should be working in radians rather than degrees so maybe that's what's going wrong as you've been assuming I'm working in radians? Also, I'm not limiting heading at all.

Comment: No problem mate, sorry I still can't spot the problem though! It won't matter if you just "thought" it was degrees, since you were only adding / subtracting 0.05 at a time. That's small enough to get a smooth rotation, it's about 3 degrees. Which library are you using for Math.cos? I strongly imagine it requires radians. But as long as you were not limiting heading by trying to keep it positive, or by adding / subtracting 360, then it will not have mattered. Try to narrow down the value of heading when it first goes wrong.

Comment: Oh, another thought! Are you using glRotatef? That DOES require degrees. But Math.cos is still likely to require radians, depending upon exactly what library you are using.

Comment: And another thought. Once you have applied the movement, do you then try to "work out" what heading was, by using trig functions like arccos / cos-1? If so you will get that problem because of the quadrants, but I think you're probably not doing that anyway. But just in case you are, you would be better off just keeping track of what heading is, rather than working it out again after the movement. If you really need to work out what heading is, based upon the movement, I can help you with that.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for all the replies, I haven't tried anything since my last comment but I think I can answer some of the questions. First of all I'm doing this in LWJGL and so using the Java Math library and after looking it up it seems it does need radians.

Comment: Yes, I am using glRotatef because when the player presses left/right the character onscreen gets rotated on the spot with glRotatef, so is it because I'm seeing my character move (heading = 90) 90 degrees with glRotatef but then when I go in that "new forward" I am actually working out the cosine of 90 radians not 90 degrees and so it is completely different?

Comment: Also, nah I'm not trying to arccos/cos-1 it afterwards, heading is a global variable for the Player class at the moment and so just use it everywhere as it is.

Comment: OK, with heading in radians, you should try glRotatef ((heading * 180) / PI, 0, 0, 1); (or whichever axis you're rotating about)

Comment: Ah! Wow I should have checked this earlier but it was that Math.cos() needs the heading in radians, thankfully the Math class provides a .toRadians() function for degrees so it was really simple to correct, now the movement is working correctly. Thanks so much for your help Dave and sorry for wasting so much of your time! :)

Comment: No worries mate, enjoy your game!